# javascript как сохранить значение при выходе из функции

Tags: javascript

Нужно передать переменную в функцию, функция изменяет значение этой переменной, как реализовать?

```
var x = ''
var y = ''
var z = ''

function test(variable) {
    variable = 'text'
}

test(x)
test(y)
test(z)

alert(x) // пусто
alert(y) // пусто
alert(z) // пусто
```

А нужно, что бы значения сохранились...

Comment: а сделать в функции `return variable` и потом делать `x = test(x)` - ни как?

Comment: @BOPOH из функции уже возвращается deferred

Comment: @user3737786, из **функции из поста** ничего не возвращается. Дополните свой вопрос деталями, иначе ответ, подходящий под код в вопросе, может быть не применим для вашего реального проекта

Comment: @BOPOH значит вы плохо прочитали вопрос или не поняли суть того, что необходимо

Comment: @user3737786, это не мне предназначалось. Если можно использовать глобальные объекты, тогда можно просто через `window[variable]` их менять, надо только не значения переменных передавать (т.е. `test(x)`), а их названия (т.е. `test('x')`)

Comment: @BOPOH, с глобальными может не прокатить в зависимости от того, как описаны эти переменные

Comment: @BOPOH да не вам, мой пардон, вообщем уже все понял, всем спасибо за отклик!

Comment: @user3737786, есть еще один способ - через eval ))) т.е. это не способ вообще, т.к. его не надо использовать, но он делает то, что [вы хотите](https://jsfiddle.net/aa869g2c/1/)

Comment: @BOPOH, :-D если _он делает то, что вы хотите_, то это вполне себе способ :-) Добавьте ваши варианты из комментариев в качестве ответа :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В яваскрипте нет возможности изменить параметр переданный в функцию, просто присвоив ему новое значение.

В качестве обходного пути можно использовать объект со свойством которое надо поменять:

```
var z = {data: ''}

function test(variable) {
    variable.data = 'text'
}

test(z); //z.data == 'text'
```

Либо возвращать значение из функции, тогда передавать ей параметр не обязательно

```
var z = ""

function test() {
    return 'text'
}

z = test(); // z == 'text'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = '';
var y = '';
var z = '';

function test(variable) {
    variable = 'text';
    return variable;
}

x = test(x);
y = test(y);
z = test(z);

alert(x);
alert(y);
alert(z);
```

Comment: если из функции уберете _variable_ ничего не поменяется

Comment: Это да. В Вашем ответе всё хорошо расписано.